# Verificar si presiona Crtl dentro del MouseEnter Vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net

Buen día, esta es una aplicación para windows creada en visual basic .net 2010.

Estoy buscando una manera de poder verificar si la persona esta presionando la tecla control cuando pasa por encima de unos paneles que tengo creados.

Necesito que la verificación se haga de esta manera ya que si esto es correcto quiero ir cambiando el color a los paneles a medida que vaya pasando sobre ellos.

Los paneles son creados en tiempo de ejecución y son muchos. Les muestro el código:

```
For i = 0 To cantidadpaneles - 1
        Dim Panel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel()
        Panel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, posalto) ' el 11 se mantiene. 
        Panel1.Name = "Panel" + numeronombre.ToString


        Panel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1800, 23) '854
        Panel1.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro


        AddHandler Panel1.Click, AddressOf Panel_Click
        AddHandler Panel1.MouseEnter, AddressOf Panel_MouseEnter  'cambia de color cuando te posicionas con el mause
        AddHandler Panel1.MouseLeave, AddressOf Panel_MouseLeave  'vuelve a su color normal cuando sacas el mause
        AddHandler Panel1.KeyPress, AddressOf Panel_KeyPress
        AddHandler Panel1.KeyDown, AddressOf Panel_KeyDown
        AddHandler Panel1.MouseDown, AddressOf Panel_MouseDown
        AddHandler Panel1.MouseMove, AddressOf Panel_MouseMove



        Panel1.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip1

        Matriz(i, 0) = Panel1.Name 'agrego a la matriz todos los paneles (nombre)
        Matriz(i, 3) = i    'guardo el nro del panel en la matriz 
        Matriz(i, 4) = posalto    'guardo la posicion en la que se crea el panel

        Me.PanelContenedor.Controls.Add(Panel1)
        posalto = posalto + 23
        numeronombre = numeronombre + 1
    Next
```

No encontré la forma de poder preguntar si presiona el control dentro del mouseEnter, pero tal vez se les ocurre alguna idea a uds.

Comment: Es que, en ese evento, se mide si el mouse entra o sale. las teclas se controlan con los eventos Key(up, down, press)... deberias pensar en que en realidad tenes que fijarte cuando se apreta CTRL, saber que esta apretado, y cuando se suelta.

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi, la solución es que almacenes en una variable si la tecla control está siendo pulsada o no.

Comment: Descubrí que el evento MouseMove permite verificar el keypress y pude realizar la acción que deseaba dentro de el. Muchas gracias por sus respuestas. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

'Has de Crear un Evento Panel_MouseMove para hacer el cambio de color de este estilo...

```
Private Sub MiFuncion(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MosueMove
' Aquí instrucciones para hacer-le el cambio de color
End Sub
```